# How to provide bean methods without EL expression

Tags: jsf, el

As I was told and found on websites, my bean will only be executed if I have a call for it on my `.xhtml`.

Is it possible to call my bean without any EL expression?

I need this because my `HomeController` is calling a method that checks for the session status and on my `home.xhtml` and don't have any need for fall this bean, for now.

Comment: You can call it from another bean or from phase listener or from somewhere else. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I have edited it, please see if more information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for a solution in a different direction.

If you're homegrowing user authentication instead of using container managed authentication, then you normally use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for the particular purpose of checking if an user is logged in or not.

The servlet filter can like as servlets (like `FacesServlet`) be mapped on a particular URL pattern. It will then be invoked on every request matching that URL pattern. You can explore request/session data in the filter and then handle the request/response accordingly by either continuning the filter chain, or by sending a redirect.

You need to implement [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) interface accordingly. Here's a kickoff example of how the `doFilter()` method should be implemented assuming that you've a `@SessionScoped` managed bean  `LoginController`. JSF stores session scoped managed beans as attributes of `HttpSession`.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    LoginController loginController = (LoginController) (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("loginController") : null;

    if (loginController == null || !loginController.isLoggedIn()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
    }
}
```

Map this filter on an URL pattern covering the restricted pages, e.g. `/app/*`.

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Update** if the `login.xhtml` is also covered by this URL pattern and you really can't change it, then change the `if` block as follows:

```
if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login.xhtml") && (loginController == null || !loginController.isLoggedIn())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: creating this class I got a list of 5 Filter classes, which is the correct?

Comment: `javax.servlet.Filter`. See also the links in the answer.

Comment: yeah..I got that, still one doubt...the @WebFilter, what does it do?

Comment: It registers the servlet filter for the webapp, like as `@ManagedBean` registers the JSF managed bean for the webapp. Previously this was done by XML configuration files. E.g. `<filter>` in `web.xml` and `<managed-bean>` in `faces-config.xml`. Again, click the link, it's explained in there as well :)

Comment: No, you should use a common URL which is shared between all restricted pages. If you have none, then you'd need to create one. E.g. create an extra folder `/app` and put all restricted pages in there. Or `/private` or `/secured` or whatever you like to name it. If you really don't want to create one, use `@WebFilter("/*")` instead, but this will filter ALL requests, including login page itself. You'd need to check for that in the filter as well.

Comment: hum...got it, in my case it will be fornecedores/views/

Comment: The URL pattern should not include the context path. It must be relative to the webcontent. Thus so, `@WebFilter("/views/*")`. Make sure that the login page is not covered by this, or you will run in an infinite redirect loop! Put it in a different folder or in the root.

Comment: is it possible to make `@WebFilter("/app/*")` skip one file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just add `!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login.xhtml")` to the `if` block  for the case you need to skip `login.xhtml`. See updated answer.

Comment: this file must be inside the WEB-INF directory? is yes, nothing happens

Comment: No, files in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible anyway. If you enter such an URL in browser, you'll only get 404s. They are only accessible if you use `RequestDispatcher#forward()` in a servlet/filter, but you don't want it here.

Comment: so what do I do? On the link you've sent me, it is telling to save on Web-inf

Comment: Oh, you mean the filter class? I understood the login XHTML file. Just create and save the filter class the same same way as you created managed bean classes. The IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans/etc) will compile and build it all automagically. Don't forget to restart the webapp in order to get it registered. Make sure that your container supports Servlet 3.0, otherwise `@WebFilter` is not recognized.

Comment: so no filter class on web-inf...I'm gonna save it on com.erp3.gui.filters, ok?